# Can I flush old bleach solution without hurting the environment much?

Tags: plumbing, water, cleaning, chemicals

I live in the Midwest. Sometimes I clean things with a bleach solution (probably about 12:1 to 24:1 water:bleach), and end up with a bucket of solution. Now I have about 1/2 gallon of water+bleach+dirt. Let's assume that I already have the bucket of solution.

Is there an amount of time that I can leave it out before it becomes close to "harmless" to dump it down my shower drain? I am concerned about my fixtures but more for the environment.

I have heard people say that it breaks down eventually into harmless chemicals, but I have also heard that it never does.

Thanks!

Comment: Septic tank or sewer? Septic tank you *might* have a reason for concern (but quite limited with only 1/2 gallon). Sewer, none, just dump it. It will be diluted and neutralized before it's halfway down the street.

Comment: People use bleach to wash clothes, some people do so incessantly. I never really gave it any thought that bleach water would hurt your plumbing. In a quick google search which seems somewhat of a business sense, it touches on all of the topics you inquire, here ya go: https://www.clorox.com/dr-laundry/bleach-101/  apparently you'd have to try real hard to cause an issue. I believe it indicates 1 year.

Comment: Thanks @Ecnerwal and @noybman! I will also add this (https://home.howstuffworks.com/bleach4.htm)[link] from howstuffworks which mostly agrees with the idea that it is usually harmless but also states that "[w]hen sodium hypochlorite gets into water or soil, it breaks down into the ions sodium, calcium, and hypochlorite; these ions can potentially react with other substances in water, but the possible effects are not known."